# binary execution in a while loop.for loop through shell script

Tags: shell

Hello i am new to shell script. want to execute a binary through loop in a shell script.
 wrote a pgm which looked like:

```
i="1"

while [ $i -lt 100 ]
do
/home/rajni/BUFFER_SEND_STUB/build/buffer_send.exe
i=`expr $i +1` 
done
```

doubt it is not working fine. Can anyone suggest????
Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you facing in this script?

Comment: Did you get any error messages?

Answer (score 2):

`expr` won't like the fact you've used `+1` rather than the space-separated `+ 1`.

I also tend to use `[[` and `]]` rather than the single ones since they're definitely bash-internal and more powerful than the external `[`/`test`.

In any case, there's a more efficient way if you're using a relatively recent `bash`:

```
for i in {1..100} ; do
    echo $i
done
```

which will do something with each value 1 through 100 inclusive (your current loop does 1 through 99 so you may have to adjust for that).

Changing that `100` to a `5` shows how it works, generating:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Note that `{1..100}` will not work in all POSIX shells; `i=$(expr $i + 1)` (or even better, `i=$((i+1))`) will.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the for loop

```
for i in {1..100}
do
    /home/rajni/BUFFER_SEND_STUB/build/buffer_send.exe
done
```

Comment: thanks for ur comment..but would it increment 'i'??????? or i have to add any command for it?

Comment: the _for_ loop increments the counter _i_ automatically.

Comment: `{1..100}` expands to the list of integers from 1 to 100, which the `for` loop then iterates over. Note that some shells (notably `dash`) do not support brace expressions.